# Multiple loops on index page with sticky post and pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination, loop, sticky-post

First post on this site. Hope to get some help from you guys. Probably a simple answer for you experts.

I have two category's (news & work). I want to show on my index page (wordpress startpage/blog) the five latest news at the top (cat. news). Below that i want to show my post (cat news & work). I also have sticky posts in the work cat, that I want to only on the first page.

I think this means three loops. one for news, one for sticky in work & news, and then one for work & news, none sticky. I can get this to work, but the problem is that my sticky post shows up first on all the pages when I paginate on the index-file (eg. press the read prev post, /page/2, /page/3 etc..

How can I make the sticky post to be sticky only on the first page (index.php)?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="news">

<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => News, 'posts_per_page' => 5)); ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!--#news-->



<div id="work">

<!-- Sticky -->

<?php if ( $paged != True ): ?>

<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'category_name' => Work)); ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif ?>





<!-- Non Sticky -->

<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'category_name' => Work, 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'paged' => $paged)); ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div><!--#work-->
```

Thanks
/K

My pagination code:

```
function pagination() {  
 global $wp_query;
 $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
 // Only paginate if we have more than one page
 if ( $total > 1 )  {
     // Get the current page
     if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
          $current_page = 1;
     // Structure of “format” depends on whether we’re using pretty permalinks
    $permalinks = get_option('permalink_structure');
    $format = empty( $permalinks ) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';
    echo paginate_links(array(
          'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
          'format' => $format,
          'current' => $current_page,
          'total' => $total,
          'mid_size' => 2,
          'prev_next' => False
    ));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you do your pagination, you can use something like `if( $page != 1 )`. This allows you you to output certain sections on only the first page. You will need to change `$page` to your pagination variable, but that is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

I added my pagination code in my question. I also added your code into mine, but there is still a sticky post on all pages.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't name the variable correctly. Change `if ( $page != 1 )` to `if ( $current_page != 1 )`, so that you'll be working with a variable that is defined.

Comment: Oooops, sorry. I have changed it now, but there is still sticky posts on all the paginated pages.

But I dont understand how that will change the display of Sticky posts. The Sticky post WP_Query have already been triggered before, and is written way before the pagination function is called.

Comment: @Keat The way I understood your question, the sticky posts were showing up in the non-sticky post query. Do you want the sticky posts query to not show up on the second page? Put whatever you want to only happen on the first page inside of the conditional (be it changing a query var, doing display, or anything else) and voilà!

Comment: @BooneGorges The pagination code was not present when I posted my answer, I could not have known the variable name.

Comment: @m0r7if3r No the non-sticky post query uses 'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), so that work as it is supposed to. But if you look at the code, the sticky post query loads every time, cause it loads before the non-sticky post (as it is supposed to).

How do I use the $page variable? Its always echo "1", no mater what page I am on (eg. /page/2, /page/3

Comment: @m0r7if3r Ok, I got the sticky post to show up on only the first page with this code:
`if( $paged != True )` 
But that makes the first page have 1 more post then the rest of the pages. Is there a solution to this? Cause I use a icon for the post, so its important for the layout with only 8 posts per page.

Comment: If this is solved, then mark it as such. Glad you got it working.